# How to count string similarity by using pandas dataframe more faster

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, similarity

I have two pandas `dataframes`, I want to count string similarity from `dataframes`. This is my code,but I got a big problem is my data too bid and my code cost too much time(maybe cost 7 days). Does any method to let my code more faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import difflib

df_post=pd.read_csv('ptt_run.csv',encoding='utf8',header=0)
df_post=df_post.fillna('null')
df_yahoo=pd.read_csv('yahoo_movie_20180519_test.csv',encoding='utf8',header=0)
df_yahoo=df_yahoo.fillna('null')

for i in range(0,len(df_yahoo)):
    df_post[df_yahoo['yahoo_movie_id'][i]]=0

    for j in range(0,len(df_post)):
        df_post.loc[j, df_yahoo['yahoo_movie_id'][i]]=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, df_yahoo['yahoo_ch_nosign'][i], df_post['title_nosign'][j]).ratio()

df_post.to_csv('df_score_test.csv', encoding='utf8',index=False)
```

my `len(df_yahoo)=6000`, `len(df_post)=130000` 
I want to know df_yahoo['yahoo_ch_nosign'][0] with df_post['title_nosign'][0~13000] similarity to df_yahoo['yahoo_ch_nosign'][6000] with df_post['title_nosign'][0~13000] similarity 
It cost too much time to do this for loop,but I don't know how to improve my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Basically doing manual looping like in your case is the slowest menthod that doesnt take advantage of built in pandas/numpy methods.

This article does a good job of clarifying the matter:  https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6